# Which action should I take if I already flagged to close outside the VLQ queue?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

If, while reviewing the VLQ queue, I come across a question that I have already voted/flagged to close, what is the proper action?

I can't vote to close it again, so 'close' doesn't work. 'Looks OK' feels wrong. So, skip?

Answer (score 1):

You'll just get "this item is not reviewable" and won't be able to review it. So you can't take any action on it except clicking "next" :)

And btw, there is no "no action needed" in VLQ review queue, there is "looks ok".

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? This is *exactly* what happens if you already closevoted outside VLQ review queue.

Comment: I didn't get that message though. :/ But if it makes a difference, it was here on MSE, and i actually flagged it for closure instead of directly voting to delete (just another 100 to go).

Comment: @Sci So ok, you didn't vote to close, but flagged for closure?